# Apache Handling Characters Strangly

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Ok I just switched servers from a shared host to a dedicated server and everything seems to be functioning the same EXCEPT for one problem.  Before I get into this I should mention both servers ran the exact same codeigniter config on top of a LAMP stack

I think it is easiest to show just by examples so here they are:

**URI:** /search/term/% 
**New Server Result:** Bad Request - Server Error
**Old Server Result:** Executes a search and returns results for %

**URI:** /search/term/%20 
**New Server Result:** Searchs and returns results for a space (the translation of %20)
**Old Server Result:** Searchs and returns results for a space (the translation of %20)

**URI:** /search/term/%2F 
**New Server Result:** Not Found - Server Error
**Old Server Result:** Searchs and returns results for a / (the translation of %2F)

I want the server to produce results in these instances just like the previous server did.

---

**UPDATE**
Senario #3 was solved but the first problem still remains and I can't figure it out.  I want to add more details about it to possible get to the bottom of it.  
The exact error message is: 
***400 Bad Request Bad; Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.***

1. When I check the apache error logs there is nothing about this error there.
2. The result is the same accross all browsers and after the cache is cleared.
3. Finally, I am pretty sure that I set up **AcceptPathInfo On** correct because when I go to the url: /robots.txt/klsdfj (not a real location) it produces the contents of the robots.txt file.  To the best of my understanding that's the proper function of this directive.

Please let me know if any further info is required I would be happy to provide it.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should take a look a the apache directive [AllowEncodedslashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) or this one : [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Regards

mimiz

Comment: Wow haha that was easy enough, part 3 solved but part 1 is still acting the same way

Comment: I put AcceptPathInfo On in my virtual host in the directory and it still hasn't fixed the first problem (still getting bad request)...I read the documentation for it and that appears to be the solution, am I putting it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing that text from a form, you will probably need to `encodeURI()` the text using Javascript and pass it to the server.  Then the server (PHP) could decode it using `rawurldecode()`.  Using your example, `%20` will become `%2520` in the URL and then the server will decode it was `%20`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Comment: currently any search form posts data to /search/index.php which takes that data encodes it and redirects to /search/term/ encoded data

Comment: The examples above were based on posted data and manually entering the URL